# Galeria pop-up de imagens

Tags: html, popup, galeria

Eu tenho num ficheiro HTML isto: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E queria que quando se clica-se numa das imagens aparecia em pop-up um slide de imagens, como uma galeria.
Algo deste género http://www.monocapa.pt/portfolio.php, alguém sabe como se faz?

Comment: Você usa jQuery, Angular, ou algum outro framework javascript no teu projeto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se quer igual o que está sendo usado neste site é o `FancyBox` um `plugin` em `JQuery`.
Neste link tem todos as instruções de como usar e o arquivos para download.
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Answer (score 3):

Use o Shadowbox JS, além de ser extremamente leve é extremamente fácil de implementar: https://github.com/mjackson/shadowbox

```
<!-- insere os arquivos do shadowbox -->
<link href='source/shadowbox.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<script src='source/shadowbox.js' type='text/javascript'/>

<!-- inicializa o shadowbox -->      
<script type='text/javascript'>Shadowbox.init();</script>
```

Usando nas suas imagens

```
<a href="imagem_grande.jpg" rel="shadowbox">
    <img src="imagem_pequena.jpg">
</a>
```